# Is there any possibility in android to resize canvas width and height dynamically on orientation change

Tags: android

I used an background image on canvas and try to re-size it accordingly when the device orientation changed, can anyone suggest me is this possible in android to re-size the canvas dimension on orientation change.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. I'd suggest you use 2 canvases for portait and landscape orientation.

Comment: thanks Neevek,  Actually i am fetching the background image from url and setting it to the canvas and have to save the image with same dimension as an output, so as u suggest i have to use two different urls for landscape and portrait orientations, is this possible to get same dimension output from both the orientations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to resize the canvas.If you are using a background image on the canvas that covers the entire screen, then what you can do is scale this image when the orientation changes in the following way :

```
@Override
        public void onSurfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                int width, int height) {


            // orientation change
            if (_width == width && _height == height) {
                _orient = 0;//portrait
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                            this._holder=holder;
                this.bgBitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(res, R.drawable.bg), (_holder
                        .getSurfaceFrame().width()), _holder.getSurfaceFrame()
                        .height(), false);

            } else {
                _orient = 1;//landscape
                this.width = width;
                this.height = height;
                his.bgBitmap =Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory
                .decodeResource(res, R.drawable.bg), (_holder
                        .getSurfaceFrame().width()), _holder.getSurfaceFrame()
                        .height(), false);

            }

            super.onSurfaceChanged(holder, format, width, height);
        }
```

This method is part of the class that extends [Engine](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/wallpaper/WallpaperService.Engine.html) in my code.My code is very lengthy so i'm posting only the relevant part here.